# Como eu posso abrir o postman pelo vba do excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Gostaria de saber como posso abrir o [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com) pelo VBA do EXCEL.

Gostaria de instanciar a aplicação como um objeto porém não sei como fazer.

Exemplo:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
With IE
End with
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não é clara... O Postman é um aplicativo para fazer requisições HTTP. Você quer fazer requisições HTTP? Você quer acessar os dados salvos no aplicativo? Onde você leu que o Postman tem alguma integração com linguagens ou outros aplicativos?

Comment: @fernandosavio Então, gostaria apenas de abrir através do VBA Excel o Postman. E instanciar em uma variável "Object".

Comment: Desculpe, mas segue não fazendo sentido (pelo menos para mim)... Talvez você consiga iniciar outro processo ou executar um binário a partir do VBA.. O que não entendo é o que você quer dizer com instanciar em uma variável. Que tipo de objeto seria essa variável? E o que você poderia fazer com essa variável?

Comment: @fernandosavio Mudando a pergunta então, como eu poderia colocar uma API no Postman e deixar em loop uma variável ?

Comment: O que eu quero em relação ao post, é como acessar através do VBA o postman, pois tenho uma parte de um arquivo API em HTML e nele preciso ficar alterando uma variável.

Answer (score 1):

Tenho quase certeza que o Postman não fornece uma interface via *ActiveX*, pois o `CreateObject` é isto, uma referencia a um [**objeto ActiveX**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/glossary/vbe-glossary#activex-object), logo é impossivel ter um objeto de algo que não suporta **ActiveX**.

Note que ActiveX é uma tecnologia Microsoft que era bastante usada no passado, mas hoje é um tanto quanto incomum. Creio que vai conseguir fazer no **máximo** é usar o `SendKeys` que creio ser especifico para VBA do Office:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg278655(v=office.14)

Um exemplo da propria documentação com a calculadora do windows:

```
Dim ReturnValue, I 
ReturnValue = Shell("CALC.EXE", 1)    ' Inicia a calculador
AppActivate ReturnValue               ' Ativa a calculadora (janela)
For I = 1 To 100                      ' 100 repetições
    SendKeys I & "{+}", True          ' Envia o numero mais o sinal de soma
Next I 
SendKeys "=", True                    ' Obtem o total
SendKeys "%{F4}", True                ' Envia ALT+F4 para fechar a calculadora
```

Eu não vou formular um exemplo com postman porque creio que vai ser algo complexo de ajustar, já que o postman parece não funcionar muito bem com o TAB (o que seria o essencial para o uso disto), ao menos eu não consegui, mas creio que isto será o mais próximo que irá chegar, segue comandos suportados:

| Tecla | Código |
| --- | --- |
| `BACKSPACE` | `{BACKSPACE}`, `{BS}` ou `{BKSP}` |
| `BREAK` | `{BREAK}` |
| `CAPS LOCK` | `{CAPSLOCK}` |
| `DEL` ou `DELETE` | `{DELETE}` ou `{DEL}` |
| `END` | `{END}` |
| `ENTER` | `{ENTER}` ou `~` |
| `ESC` | `{ESC}` |
| `HELP` | `{HELP}` |
| `HOME` | `{HOME}` |
| `INS` ou `INSERT` | `{INSERT}` ou `{INS}` |
| `NUM LOCK` | `{NUMLOCK}` |
| `PAGE DOWN` | `{PGDN}` |
| `PAGE UP` | `{PGUP}` |
| `LEFT ARROW` | `{LEFT}` |
| `RIGHT ARROW` | `{RIGHT}` |
| `UP ARROW` | `{UP}` |
| `DOWN ARROW` | `{DOWN}` |
| `PRINT SCREEN` | `{PRTSC}` |
| `SCROLL LOCK` | `{SCROLLLOCK}` |
| `TAB` | `{TAB}` |
| `F1` | `{F1}` |
| `F2` | `{F2}` |
| `F3` | `{F3}` |
| `F4` | `{F4}` |
| `F5` | `{F5}` |
| `F6` | `{F6}` |
| `F7` | `{F7}` |
| `F8` | `{F8}` |
| `F9` | `{F9}` |
| `F10` | `{F10}` |
| `F11` | `{F11}` |
| `F12` | `{F12}` |
| `F13` | `{F13}` |
| `F14` | `{F14}` |
| `F15` | `{F15}` |
| `F16` | `{F16}` |

Para especificar chaves combinadas com qualquer combinação das teclas "SHIFT", "CTRL" e "ALT", anteceda o código da chave com um ou mais dos seguintes códigos:

| Tecla | Código |
| --- | --- |
| `SHIFT` | `+` |
| `CTRL` | `^` |
| `ALT` | `%` |

---

**No entanto** (eu não posso afirmar porque nunca usei) você pode experimentar usar os próprios recursos do postman que parece que fornecem ambientes de criação de scripts para automatizar tarefas dentro do próprio postman, ao menos foi o que me pareceu com esta esta página: https://www.getpostman.com/postman-features (aonde esta escrito "Scripts and the Postman Sandbox"), creio que seja isto:

- https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/intro_to_scripts/

Agora se tiver uma pergunta especifica, como por exemplo:

> como acessar um documento html e pegar uma certa variável para aplicar em uma requisição no postman?

Creio que será uma pergunta diferente e que você estude primeiro a API que lhe indiquei para ver a possibilidade e então se tiver dificuldade formule a pergunta.